# I gave a scammer my address, full name, and phone number. What can they do?

Tags: fraud, scams

It was for a job as a personal assistant. She is sending me a check. I am suppose to buy some to toys for an orphanage and deduct my check from it.

Now I am scared about what can they do with the information I have provided.
The check was supposed to arrive here yesterday. She send me a message saying the check will be delivered to me tomorrow by Fedex to my address.

Comment: What makes you sure it's a scam?

Comment: The chance that that check from her is good is slim to none. I'd just tear it up and be done with it.

Answer (score 5):

Did you give anything besides name, address, and phone? Like social security number or account numbers?

If so, I'd talk to wherever that account number is applicable, the bank or whatever, and see about getting the number changed.

If you just gave your name and address ... Probably mostly that just sets you up to get lots more scam letters and phone calls. Of itself, that doesn't give a scammer access to your money or anything. They can get name, address, and phone of thousands of people from the phone book and other public sources.

But scammers can be resourceful. They might be able to use the fact that they know your name, address, and phone to convince a business that they are you and to give them information about accounts you own, etc.

I wouldn't panic, but I would keep an eye on things for a while. Get a copy of your credit report and make sure no one's taken out loans in your name or that sort of thing. Check with social security and make sure no one's collecting disability payments in your name. Etc. If nothing suspicious happens within a few months, you're probably okay.

Anyone on here able to give more specific advice?